# How to code buttons with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, button, printing

I have a vba script for a button that puts a button on each sheet in my workbook. I want to program these buttons so that each time they are pressed they call a print script that will print the information on the sheets.  Here is the code I have for the buttons:

```
Sub AddButtons()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim btn As Button

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set btn = ws.Buttons.Add(625, 0, 50, 25)
        Call pageprintTEST1(ws)
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Here is the code I have for the print script:

```
Sub pageprintTEST1(ws As Excel.Worksheet)
 Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
         Worksheets(ws).Activate
   With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ws).PageSetup
        .PrintArea = "A1:O48"
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ws).PrintOut
```

I have been having a few problems with this. First, this script adds buttons to every sheet, and I only want buttons added to the sheets from sheet 5 onward (so no buttons on the first 4 sheets). Second it doesn't wait for me to click the button before opening the printer dialogue box, and once you choose a printer it says error Mismatch.

I looked into how to pass variables to different subs and the call method, and this seemed right, but now I am not sure where I went wrong. I would really appreciate if anyone had any advice or knew what to do!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `OnAction` property of the button to store the macro name, but you can't pass an object variable to it. Since the button can only be clicked when its sheet is active, you can use this:

```
Sub AddButtons()
    Dim btn As Button
    Dim n As Long

    For n = 5 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Set btn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n).Buttons.Add(625, 0, 50, 25)
        btn.OnAction = "pageprintTEST1"
    Next
End Sub

Sub pageprintTEST1()
 Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
   With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintArea = "A1:O48"
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut
End Sub
```

Comment: Should remove that `ws` from `Next ws`

Comment: @AgentRev Well spotted - sloppy hacking on my part. Corrected.

Comment: When I ran the code you gave me, after pressing the button, I got a popup  that read "Cannot run the macro 'Solution_0729_test.xlsm!pageprintTEST1'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled." However the other macros I have seem to work. Any ideas why I could be getting this?

Comment: Which module is the `pageprintTEST1` routine in, and did you edit it as I showed?

Comment: Yes, I copied exactly what you wrote. Both the button macro and the pageprintTEST1 macro are simply ion vba window This Workbook (Code) so I am not sure which module.

Comment: The `pageprintTEST1` macro works when run by itself, the error only comes up when the button is pressed. Any ideas?

Comment: The macro needs to be in a normal module not ThisWorkbook

Comment: Great thank you! adding the pageprintTEST1 maccro to a new module (module 1) worked with the code you provided!